# whats wrong with this trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem when ever i try to execute this trigger on my database it just wont work i need to know if the problem is in the trigger itself

```
CREATE TRIGGER Anzahlupdate
AFTER INSERT ON Kaufvorgang
REFERENCING NEW AS neu
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE gekauft SMALLINT;
    DECLARE altAnzahl SMALLINT;
    SET gekauft (select Stueckzahl from Kaufvorgang k where k.id = neu.id);
    SET altAnzahl (select Anzahl from Artikelangebot a where  a.id = neu.id);
    IF gekauft <= altAnzahl THEN
        UPDATE Artikelangebot SET Anzahl = (altAnzahl -gekauft) where a.id = neu.id;
    END IF;
END@
```

Comment: _"it just wont work"_ How exactly, can you describe the details of errors and/or unexpected results?

Comment: The published code looks more like db2 and you can't just drop db2 code into mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is for MySQL wrong.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Anzahlupdate
AFTER INSERT ON Kaufvorgang
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE gekauft SMALLINT;
    DECLARE altAnzahl SMALLINT;
    SET gekauft = (select Stueckzahl from Kaufvorgang k where k.id = new.id);
    SET altAnzahl = (select Anzahl from Artikelangebot a where  a.id = new.id);
    IF gekauft <= altAnzahl THEN
        UPDATE Artikelangebot SET Anzahl = (altAnzahl - gekauft) where a.id = new.id;
    END IF;
END;
```

Depending where you want to enter the code you eventually need also `DELIMITER`

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html